# PHP: Cannot post /practice.php

Tags: php, html

I have 3 inputs with a submit button, an extremely basic setup that I've created to allow me to toy with PHP a bit. Below is my HTML code for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
<title>PHP TEST</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="practice.php" method="post">

    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>Name:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="username" size="30" /> </td>
    </tr>

        <tr>
    <td>Address:</td>
    <td> <input type="text" name="Address" size="30" /> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
    <td>City:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="Address" size="30"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>        
    <td colspan="Z" align="center"> <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> </td>
    </tr>
        </table>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<html>
<head>  
<title>PHP TEST SCRIPT</ttle>   
</head>

    <body>

    <?php

    echo"<p>Data Processed</>"; 

    ?>


    </body>

</html>
```

Most of the working solutions in similar questions ask seem to involve usually the developer not providing the proper directory to the PHP file, however, my PHP file shares the same directory as my HTML file, so I'm not sure what the issue might be as both are located in: /home/tornado711/PHP/ I suspect the issue might be a typo that I made or some basic mistake, but it seems my eye for detail is failing me right now.

Answer (score 3):

You have an HTML typo in your PHP page

```
<title>PHP TEST SCRIPT</ttle>
```

Should be

```
<title>PHP TEST SCRIPT</title>
```

Happens sometimes lol You might want to make sure you use a good IDE. Most of them would have highlighted that for you as you type.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out to me! That's one less thing to worry about. I was hoping that would fix the error I was experiencing sadly it did not though :( but thank you for pointing that out to me! Yes I just noticed the IDE did highlight it, I must've accidentally skipped over it!

Comment: The code seems to work fine in local with the title tag element changed. If you're still having a problem, then the only thing I can think of is a typo in the name of the file you call "practice.php". is the file really named that and in the same folder as the form? Cause as I said, it works on my side.

Comment: Odd, when I switch over to windows and just copy my code into a regular folders and fix the title issue, it works perfectly fine! Yet my code over in my linux environment (the main environment I use for web development) will not behave. Could it perhaps have something to do with the Linux file system being handled differently than you'd expect from something when writing HTML/PHP in Windows?

EDIT: So it seems the issue is the IDE I'm using. I'm using "Brackets" and for some reason using it and the "live preview feature" causes PHP to not work!

Comment: You might want to make sure you're saving your file in UTF-8 and not in ANSI. Also, you should sanitise your code with notepad (Copy-paste in notepad then copy-paste in your IDE) that will get rid of any NULL bytes that could be invisible. When your upload, make sure the file has the right OWNER and is in 0644.